Why is the 4-current a tensor rather than a tensor density?
I am trying to understand electromagnetism better in terms of tensors and differential geometry. First recall that (in the Lorenz gauge) the equation of motion for the four-potential $A^\mu$ is
$$(-\partial_t^2+\partial_x^2+\partial_y^2+\partial_z^2)A^\mu = -\mu_0 J^\mu.$$
My question is how does the 4-current $J^\mu$ transform under a generic change of coordinates? I know that it transforms like a vector but I am confuses as to why since it is ultimately a current density? After all, its components are the charge density, $\rho$, and the current density, J. And, of course, the units of charge density are $C/m^3$ and of current density are $C/(m^2 s)$.
Edit: To spell out my concern about units suppose that I were to implement a global conformal transformation $(t,x,y,z)\mapsto(\bar{t},\bar{x},\bar{y},\bar{z})$ which rescales 1 meter to down 1 foot. Then wouldn't $J^\mu$ be rescaled by $(1\text{ meter}/1\text{ foot})^3$? But this isn't how $J^\mu$ would transform if it were a vector field.
I guess I am confused about how we can combine together a bunch of densities and end up with a tensor instead of a tensor density (which transforms differently than a tensor).
Let's simplify the situation (and actually what follows is the scenario that I really care about). Consider a scalar version of electromagnetism in $n=1+1$ dimensions. The theory is now about the dynamics of a scalar field $\varphi$ given some charge density $\rho$. Note in this theory both of these are scalar fields in their own right and not a component of some other field. Let's say the equation of motion for $\varphi$ is
$$(-\partial_t^2+\partial_x^2)\varphi = -\rho/\epsilon_0$$
where $\rho$ is the scalar charge density which sources this scalar field. Does $\rho$ transform like a scalar or a scalar density? Again I know from this equation that it transforms like a scalar, but I want to know why.
Consider the following bit of hand waving. At any point $p=(t,x)$ define $Q(p)$ to be the total charge to the left of $p$ minus the total charge to the right of $p$. Now $Q$ is clearly a scalar field. Isn't $\rho$ essentially the derivative of $Q$? But then how is $\rho$ a scalar?
Edit: It has been pointed out that $Q$ as I have defined it above depends upon what frame I am using to define it. To fix this, consider the space-like region to the left of $p$ and the space-like region to the right of $p$. Note that these are completely disjoint and can be defined in a coordinate-independent way. Take $Q_\text{alt}(p)$ to be defined as the difference in charges between these two regions. Now define $\rho_\text{alt}$ as the derivative of $Q_\text{alt}$. How does $\rho_\text{alt}$ transform and what makes it different from how $\rho$ transforms?

I think you've just gotten yourself confused with the $Q(p)$ argument. $\varphi$ and $\rho$ are scalar fields, and $A^\mu$ and $J^\mu$ are vector fields. There's one universal transformation law for scalar fields, and another universal transformation law for vector fields. The flaw in your reasoning is assuming that $Q(t, x)$ is a scalar field. It's not, because "the total charge to the left" really means "the total charge to the left at some moment in some reference frame", which does depend on frame.

To be more explicit, suppose $Q(0, 0) = 0$. If $Q$ were actually a scalar field, then we would expect that under any standard Lorentz boost, which leaves the point $x = t = 0$ invariant, $Q$ remains zero. But in fact, under such a boost, you change the set of points $t = 0$ because simultaneity is different in different reference frames, and thereby can make $Q$ become nonzero.

If you're more used to nonrelativistic physics, it helps to think about the same thing in two space dimensions and zero time dimensions. Suppose $\varphi(x, y)$ is a scalar. Then your definition of $Q(0, 0)$ involves "the net charge to the left of $y = 0$" which clearly depends on the orientation of the axes. So a rotation centered at the origin will change $Q(0, 0)$, so it can't be a scalar.

Hello @knzhou, thanks for your comments. I have updated the post with an attempt at a coordinate-independent definition of $Q(p)$. This might still fail though because I haven't completely spelled out the sense in which $\rho_\text{alt}$ is the derivative of $Q$.
I would also appreciate your thoughts on the added note about how $J^\mu$ transforms under a global rescaling of the coordinate system (e.g., from meters to feet).


My question is how does the 4-current $J^\mu$ transform under a generic change of coordinates? I know that it transforms like a vector but I am confuses as to why since it is ultimately a current density? After all, its components are the charge density, $\rho$, and the current density, J. And, of course, the units of charge density are $C/m^3$ and of current density are $C/(m^2 s)$.

It is sometimes called current, but it is actually electric current density four-vector. Its spatial components are both a "current density" in the usual physics sense and the whole is a four-vector, these two things do not contradict each other. The description "current density" does not imply this quantity is a tensor density (needed to be multiplied by some correction factor to get a tensor). Maybe the problem is just this misleading language.
Also it seems to me you have a too ambitious expectation of what the concept of four-vector means. The definition is that its components transform the same way as the cartesian coordinates and time of an event when changing inertial frame, that is, via the Lorentz transformation. Changes of scale or units of length are not considered in this definition, and such coordinate transformations are not covered by standard Lorentz transformations! Different four-vector quantities can change differently when changing units of length.
This can be directly seen for $A^\mu$ and $J^\mu$  from the equations
$$(-\partial_t^2+\partial_x^2+\partial_y^2+\partial_z^2)A^\mu = -\mu_0 J^\mu,
$$
where $t,x,y,z$ and any lengths or times are measured in seconds, and
$$(-\partial_{t'}^2+\partial_{x'}^2+\partial_{y'}^2+\partial_{z'}^2)A'^\mu = -\mu_0 J'^\mu.
$$
where lengths and times are measured in milliseconds (thousand times smaller units).
Because the derivatives act only on $A$ and not on $J$, these two four-vectors have to transform differently when changing the units of length. $J$ scales as $q/x^3$ and $A$ scales as $q/x$, so $J$ will decrease billion times, while $A$ will decrease only thousand times. But when the units are fixed, and  inertial frames are changes, both quantities transform as four-vectors.
Another way to say this is that while the d'Alembert operator
$$
(-\partial_t^2+\partial_x^2+\partial_y^2+\partial_z^2)
$$
produces the same thing in all inertial frames (assuming all use the same units of time and length), and thus the equations above allow for $A$,$J$ to be Lorentz four-vectors, it does not produce the same thing when the coordinate system is changed via change of units, and thus the equations above do not allow for $A$ and $J$ to re-scale the same way.

First of all, the electromagnetic wave equation given in the question  is valid (assuming the Lorenz gauge condition) only in flat or at least Ricci-flat spacetime. In general curved spacetime there is an additional term proportional to the Ricci tensor.
The $J$ that appears in this equation is a tensor, not a tensor density. The quantity $J \sqrt{-g}$ is a tensor density and its four components are the charge and current density. $J \sqrt{-g}$ satisfies a continuity equation with partial derivatives, i.e., $\partial_i (J^i \sqrt{-g}) = 0$, which is interpreted as conservation of charge in the local coordinates, while $J$ instead satisfies $\nabla_i J^i = 0$.
Addendum (April 11, 2024): In 1+1 spacetime, it is not correct that $\varphi$ is a scalar field. The electromagnetic potential still has two components, call them $\varphi$ and $A$, which transform as a vector, e.g., $\varphi^2 - A^2$ is invariant under Lorentz transformations (i.e., a scalar, though not a gauge-invariant one), while $\varphi$ and $A$ separately are not. There is no magnetic field, but we would have $E = -\partial_x \varphi - \partial_t A$, so the spacelike component of the potential is still relevant.
The equation $-\partial_t^2 \varphi + \partial_x^2 \varphi = - \rho/\epsilon_0$ is not correct even assuming that the spacetime is flat. The quantity $\varphi$ on the left is a component of a vector, and the quantity on the right also should be. $\rho$ is neither a scalar, nor a component of a vector. $\rho$ is, again, the time component of $J\sqrt{-g}$ where $J$ is a vector.
The OP's attempt to provide a coordinate-independent definition of $\rho$ (which would make it a scalar) is confused. Intuitively, $\rho$ simply cannot be a scalar because it is subject to length contraction. The OP refers to "the space-like region to the left of $p$ and the space-like region to the right of $p$", but these are regions of spacetime, not regions of space. To calculate the amount of charge to the left or right of $p$, it is necessary to take the intersections of these regions with the space-like slice defined by the current coordinate system (i.e., the set of all spacetime points with $t = 0$ or whatever the current time is), which means you end up with something that depends on the coordinate system.

Hello Brian, thanks for your comments. I know that $J^\mu$ and $\rho$ transform as a vector and as a scalar respectively. What I am confused about is where my other lines of thinking go wrong. For instance, @knzhou has pointed out some issues with the Q(p) line of thought which I am working on addressing.
As I noted in the post, what I am mostly confused about is the meaning of the word "density". It seems to have two meanings which I am somehow confusing with each other.

Meaning 1: Something might be called a "density" because it is some quantity per unit volume or per unit area. Meaning 2: Something might be called a "density" because of how it transforms under coordinate transformations (i.e., with some power of the Jacobian). I know that these concepts must be distinct, but they seem to be the same thing to me, especially in the case of global (or even local) conformal transformations. See my added comments in the post about switching from a coordinate system based on meters to a coordinate system which is based on feet.

@DanielGrimmer Yes, the word "density" has two meanings as you described. In this particular case the two meanings coincide. Whether they always coincide is a different question which is not alluded to in your original post. As such, it should be posted separately rather than in the comment section. I will try to address some of your other questions shortly.

@DanielGrimmer Note that your concerns about the apparent contradiction resulting from a conformal transformation is already addressed by the part of my answer that says that the four-vector $J$ is not actually the charge and current density. The charge and current density are $J \sqrt{-g}$.
